# How to change orientation of some pages in iOS 16 in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, screen-rotation

I want to change orientation of some pages in my app in Xamarin Forms.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac and Xcode version 12.4

I have used DependencyService. It is working fine till iOS 15 but not able to rotate in iOS 16.

I am sharing sample code for reference.

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, [Transient] UIWindow forWindow)
    {
        if (App.IsAllowRotation)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
        }

        else
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
    }
```

**Service in iOS**

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationHandler
{

    public void Landscape()
    {
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight), new NSString("orientation"));
    }

    public void Portrait()
    {
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
    }
}
```

Till iOS 15 it is working fine. For iOS 16, I am trying to update Service by adding below code:

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationHandler
{

    public void Landscape()
    {

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))
        {
            
            var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);
           
            if (windowScene != null)
            {
                var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
                if (nav != null)
                {                        
                    nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();

                    windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate(
                        new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                        error => { }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
        }
    }

    public void Portrait()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(16, 0))
        {

            var windowScene = (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ConnectedScenes.ToArray()[0] as UIWindowScene);

            if (windowScene != null)
            {
                var nav = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
                if (nav != null)
                {
                    // Tell the os that we changed orientations so it knows to call GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations again

                    nav.SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations();

                    windowScene.RequestGeometryUpdate(
                        new UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait),
                        error => { }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
        }
    }
 }
```

I am getting errors for methods -
SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations(),
RequestGeometryUpdate,
UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS

May I know any namespace is required?

What changes need to be done for iOS 16 in Service and AppDelegate in Xamarin Forms iOS app?

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve 1. Services/OrientationService.cs(29,29): Error CS1061: 'UIViewController' does not contain a definition for 'SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations' and no accessible extension method 'SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations' accepting a first argument of type 'UIViewController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: 2. Services/OrientationService.cs(33,33): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

3. Services/OrientationService.cs(37,37): Error CS1061: 'UIWindowScene' does not contain a definition for 'RequestGeometryUpdate' and no accessible extension method 'RequestGeometryUpdate' accepting a first argument of type 'UIWindowScene' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods `SetNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()`, `RequestGeometryUpdate`, `UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS` are newly added methods in UIKit in [iOS16 Release Note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ipados-16-release-notes#:%7E:text=UIKit,use%20%60%2D%5BUIViewController%20setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface). I tried it in XCode14.1 and VS2022 and there is no error. According to the [XCode release version](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/), XCode14.0 starts to support iOS16. It is recommended that you update the XCode version to the latest version and try again.

Comment: Thanks. As per your comment I will update Xcode version and try it.

Comment: Ok, waiting for your updates.

Comment: If I am running app on iPhone having iOS 12.5 then also I have to install Xcode 14 and VS 2022?

Comment: If you need to write programs for iOS16, you can update your version to use some newer methods and controls.

Comment: Ok. I will update.

Comment: I have updated Xcode 14.1 and VS 2022 for mac. It's working now. Thank you so much.